# Outlook 2010 Table Cell Width Showing Incorrectly

Tags: html, html-email, outlook-2010

I am having a similar problem coding this email for Outlook 2010 (of course). The email is fine in most client but the width of the text ares is bigger than it should be. No matter what CSS, or html width I apply Outlook is rendering the width of the cell wider than it should be.

- [Preview Email Clients](http://publishingresources.createsend.com/screens/y/59CCE1BB12990B7D)
- [Web View](http://clientfiles.priworks.com/APAemails/2011_07_Fall_Forum/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with your colspans and rowspans. I recommend ditching them completely and layering tables instead. This will give you something similar to CSS.

Create one "container" table that is 1 column by 3 rows. Then create a new table in the top row for the header, one table in center for the body, and one in the bottom for a footer.

Then if you need to break things down even further, keep adding tables.

Good luck!

Comment: aha, that's brilliant and seems to be THE answer I have been looking for in all my html email nightmares. Will have to revamp it. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to do it that way in Photoshop, you will have to do the big slices first. Then open the sliced images and reslice them. That way you will get a new table each time.

The slicing feature is nice in Photoshop, but don't count on it to be right for designing an email in HTML. It's the same as with Dreamweaver. You can't build your table in the Design view and expect the HTML to be compatible with email.

Comment: YES YES YES!  This is solid gold, such an easy fix but so effective for cumbersome Outlook 2012! Fixed my issues immediatley.  Brilliant!